# Windows Authentication not prompting

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core

I am currently working on a .NET Core MVC project and I am trying to enable Windows Authentication. I tried following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) but could not get it to work as there is no prompt for Windows login.

Here's my following edit:

1. In my `Startup.cs`, I have added the line `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`
2. In my `launchSetting.json` (because I am using IIS Express), I have enabled Windows Authentication and set override to true.
3. In my `Controller`, I have labeled `[Authorized]` at the `View` method.
4. I have also ticked the `Enable Windows Authentication` at the project debug page.

I am not sure what else I am missing to enable the Windows Authentication, may I have sought some advice on this problem?

> Update: One thing to note: I did not follow the web.config codes in the doc because it's invalid for .NET Core.

Comment: Have you disabled anonymous authentication in IIS? If that is still enabled, Windows Auth will be ignored.

Comment: @DeanOC Yes, I have set Anonymous authentication to false and override property to true as well for it.